# Scala execution of abstract classes with case

Tags: scala

I'm new to Scala and I am following this tutorial http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/scala-for-java-programmers.html in which there is an example of case class usage.

I was trying to execute the example below:

```
package classes

abstract class Tree 
case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree
case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree {

    type Environment = String => Int

    def eval(t: Tree, env: Environment): Int = t match {
        case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
        case Var(n) => env(n)
        case Const(v) => v
    }
}
```

But the thing is that I couldn't execute it and I suspect that the reason is that I cannot add a main method there because it is a class and not an object. So I created an object with a main method there:

```
package classes

object TreeOperations {
    type Environment = String => Int //XXX: cannot I import it somehow?

    def main(args: Array[String]) {    
      // evaluating (x+x)+(7+y) expression
        val exp: Tree = Sum(Sum(Var("x"), Var("x")),Sum(Const(7), Var("y")))
        val env: Environment = { case "x" => 5 case "y" => 7} // x := 5, y := 7
        println("Expression: " + exp)
        println("Evaluation with x=5, y=7: " + eval(exp, env)) //XXX no eval here
    }
}
```

But then I noticed two things:

1. I cannot get access to type Environment because it is a differnent class (I tried Tree.Environment but it didn't work).
2. I cannot get access to eval(...) as well (and I tried the same).

So I wanted to know what would be the best way of solving these difficulties.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial, I don't see where they are saying that the type declaration and the `eval` method should be defined inside the `Const` case class. I would put these outside the case classes but inside the same object or an object that you import, something like this:

Put all your definitions in one or multiple files (in that case just make sure you import the declarations when needed):

```
package classes

abstract class Tree 
case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree
case class Var(n: String) extends Tree
case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree
```

In the TreeOperations file, you would have the following:

```
package classes

import Tree._

object TreeOperations {
  type Environment = String => Int //XXX: cannot I import it somehow?

  def eval(t: Tree, env: Environment): Int = t match {
    case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
    case Var(n) => env(n)
    case Const(v) => v
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) {    
    // evaluating (x+x)+(7+y) expression
    val exp: Tree = Sum(Sum(Var("x"), Var("x")),Sum(Const(7), Var("y")))
    val env: Environment = { case "x" => 5 case "y" => 7} // x := 5, y := 7
    println("Expression: " + exp)
    println("Evaluation with x=5, y=7: " + eval(exp, env)) //XXX no eval here
  }
}
```

Comment: What I would like to have is one class/object per file, i.e. one Tree.scala and another one TreeOperations.scala with the main method, is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can, just be sure to import the relevant types, i.e. Tree, Sum,... The `TreeOperations` object should then contain the operation `eval` and the definition of the type Environment. I'm updating my answer.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I didn't know I had to import the other class in order to be able to access to it inside the object. In this way I can define everything in my Tree class and then use the object only for the main method, which is exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I wanted to know why you removed the `import Tree._` in your last edit. I saw the import is necessary for me, shouldn't it be?

Comment: There was no `import Tree._`, what I had added was `import Definitions._` but back then the declarations were put in a `Definitions` object. This is not necessary though as described above and you don't need to import anything here as the case classes and the abstract class are in the same package as the operations object.

Comment: Ok. I realized I need the import because I am puting both definitions and functions inside Tree class.

Comment: @Peter, I went ahead and added that import as the problem doesn't get solved without it as discussed [in meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222675/). If you would rather leave it out, and explain as you did in the comments that it shouldn't be necessary because of the Definitions object, that's cool too, so long as the information is there for someone who may get caught up by it in the future (and not just hidden in the comments which may be deleted in the future).

Answer (score -1):

I'd write it like this:

```
package classes

abstract class Tree 

case class Sum(l: Tree, r: Tree) extends Tree

case class Var(n: String) extends Tree

case class Const(v: Int) extends Tree {

    type Environment = String => Int

    def eval(t: Tree, env: Environment): Int = t match {
        case Sum(l, r) => eval(l, env) + eval(r, env)
        case Var(n) => env(n)
        case Const(v) => v
    }
}

object AppMain extends App {
    // evaluating (x+x)+(7+y) expression
    val exp: Tree = Sum(Sum(Var("x"), Var("x")),Sum(Const(7), Var("y")))
    val env: Environment = { case "x" => 5 case "y" => 7} // x := 5, y := 7
    println("Expression: " + exp)
    println("Evaluation with x=5, y=7: " + eval(exp, env)) //XXX no eval here
}
```

[scala-api docs for App](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.App)

Comment: What I would like to have is one class/object per file, i.e. one Tree.scala and another one TreeOperations.scala with the main method, is this possible?

Comment: And one more thing: I already checked that I cannot get access to Environment type in AppMain object if I do it this way. And I tried declaring Environment type out of the class and it didn't work.